# React props giving me error : Cannot destructure property 'dispatch' of 'props' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I dont understand why I'm getting this error because they are all selectors I am using in other components. And this component is basically a copy of another one. I was under the impression that the props in { } = props where coming from my imported selectors.

But i'm getting this error;

`Cannot destructure property 'exchange' of 'props' as it is undefined.`
And it's the same error for any props i'm trying to pass to `{ } = props`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Spinner from './Spinner'
import {
    allTokensLoadedSelector,
    allTokensSelector,
    web3Selector,
    exchangeSelector
} from '../store/selectors'
import { loadToken } from '../store/interactions'

const showTokens = (data, props) => {
    const { dispatch, exchange, web3 } = props
    return (

    <tbody>
        { data.allTokens.map( (token) => {
            return(
            <OverlayTrigger trigger={['hover', 'focus' ]} key={token.tokenId} placement='top' overlay={ <Tooltip className="tooltip" id={token.TokenId}>
                {`Click to load ${token.symbol} market`}
                    </Tooltip>
                }
                >
                <tr key={token.tokenId} className="order-book-order" onClick={(e)=> loadToken(web3, exchange, token.tokenAddress, dispatch)}
                    >
                    <td>{token.symbol}/ETH</td>
                </tr>
            </OverlayTrigger>
            )
        })}
    </tbody>
    )
}

class Market extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.exchange)
        return (
        <div className="vertical">
            <div className="card bg-transparent text-white">
                <div className="card-header">
                    Market
                </div>
                <div className="card-body order-book">
                    <table className="table bg-transparent text-white table-sm small">
                        { this.props.showTokens ? showTokens(this.props) :
                        <Spinner type='table' /> }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const tokensLoaded = allTokensLoadedSelector(state)
    return {
        showTokens: tokensLoaded,
        allTokens: allTokensSelector(state),
        web3: web3Selector(state),
        exchange: exchangeSelector(state),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Market);
```

So where do I have to look to fix this I dont get it.

Comment: `showTokens` has 2 arguments, you're only passing one. Hence 2nd argument, `props`, will be undefined by default. Then you try to destructure it, so that's causing the error

Comment: So how do i pass props to it?

Comment: @Jayce444 I have added evrything. If i try to pass data as well to showTokens it says it's undefine.

Comment: What/where is the "data" the `showTokens` function is expecting?

Comment: i got it! removed data from there and pass it down to props!

Answer (score -1):

Right now you're in this weird middle ground where `showTokens` is just a function but you want it to be a function component, so let's make it a function component.

Since it's now a component, it needs a CamelCase name.  It needs to take one argument which is an object of props, and we can destructure those props immediately. Change

```
const showTokens = (data, props)
```

to

```
const ShowTokens = ({dispatch, exchange, web3, allTokens})
```

`allTokens` is now a top-level prop (not a property of data), so change

```
data.allTokens.map
```

to

```
allTokens.map
```

We want to call the component using JSX syntax, and we want to pass through all of the props which `Market` got from `mapStateToProps`.  Change

```
this.props.showTokens ? showTokens(this.props)
```

to

```
this.props.ShowTokens ? <ShowTokens {....this.props}/>
```